# uploading photo through programing in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I upload a photo to a server with the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone)

i am new in this programming and in my application i want to upload photo to facebook 
and i just do login with facebook now please tell me how can i do if any example for uploading photo to facebook then please give me (source code)
thanks

Comment: *I don't want to copy & paste the code for you here you can navigate to one of the links below* http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=30423 And this also is a very useful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750328/documented-process-for-using-facebook-connect-for-the-iphone-to-upload-photos

Comment: this is not write my code for me site.. post your code ...

Comment: May be following links are help to you. http://sree.cc/iphone/upload-an-image-from-iphone-to-server http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939335/upload-image-from-iphone-to-the-server-folder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426755/how-to-upload-image-to-remote-server-in-iphone http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/12020-uploading-image-via-http-post-request.html