# Adding NSData into NSDirectory (JSON) getting Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteMutableData) error

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am trying to add an Image into my JSON file that I want to post on the server. I am using the following code but I keep on getting `Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteMutableData)` error. The code is

```
NSDictionary *parameter = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
parameter = @{@"body":@"Hi",@"image":imageData};
```

Also, I am using `AFNetworking` to post the image to the server

I am not sure what is wrong in the code. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: See this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234186/afnetworking-uploading-a-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone else has the same problem later. this is the code that you should use

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api-base-url.com"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"], 0.5);
NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"body":@"image"};
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload" parameters:parameter constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Source : [link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: Where did you specify that multipart in the block correspond to the key 'image'? With the line 'NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"body":@"image"};', image is a value for body key.

Comment: @AnandKumar read it carefully once, its all there. the very next line defines it. here I assigned my body the value "Image" (which is a string), below that I add the @"avatar" which is the MultipartFormData

Comment: @Jonathon Thanks for the reply. But as your initial question, didn't you actually want the image data to go as the value for a key named 'image'? As per your initial question, 'image' is a key and not a value of another key.

Answer (score 1):

try like this ,

```
parameter = @{@"body":@"Hi",@"image":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,imageData]};
```

Comment: Sunny, wont this send the image as a string to the server? it should be a File for the server to accept it, or else I get an error

Comment: once see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426755/how-to-upload-image-to-remote-server-in-iphone